# How to fetch PHP database values in Json?

Tags: php, json

I have to create Matrix tree view in my project. So am plan to use **json**. My question is how to fetch **PHP** values in Json ?. I did static matrix tree but i want dynamic. Thank you for advance.

My code is following:

```
<?php
include('db.php');
$select = mysql_query("select * from table1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select))
{
?>
{
 "name": "A", // Here database values come $row['name']; 
 "children": [



  {
   "name": "B",
   "children": [
    {"name": "B-1"}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "C",
   "children": [
    {"name": "C-1", "size": 1082},

    {"name": "C-2", "size": 1681}
   ]
  },



  {
   "name": "D",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "D-1",
     "children": [
      {"name": "D-1 1", "size": 1302},


      {"name": "D-1 2", "size": 6703}
     ]
    },

   {"name": "D-2", "size": 16540}
   ]
  }
 ]
}
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Dou you also get all the chilrens from the database or how will you get the mapping with children objects?

Comment: <insert obligatory **dont use mysql driver its bad, dangerous and removed in php7** message here>

Answer (score 1):

> In this example Im using the mysqli driver. **Do not use the mysql driver**.

you just need to convert your output data into a json object.

Its possible to extract [all the rows at once](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) which is going to give you a marginally less overhead.

```
$data = mysqli_fetch_all($select); // returns everything in an associative array
$json_data = json_encode($data); // converts that array to json.
```

if you need specific keys, then manipulate your query to rename columns as necessary eg.

```
$query = "select name as firstname from ....";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just retrieve data from your database and store it in arrays like you normally would. Then call PHP's built in function `json_encode()` to transform your PHP array into json (assuming your PHP array is well formed (which should be the case if you get it out of a database)).

You could argue that this is slower because you're iterating over the data twice instead of once, but it shouldn't matter, the complexity remains the same.

Comment: Ya i fefer this link [Refer Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) but i don't know to declare variable in json and how to fetch in PHP ?  Thank you